# change of one value in the state react

Tags: reactjs

In the state I have data array that look like this

```
{
    "offers" : [
        {
          "model": "shoes",
          "availability": false,
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "model": "t-shirt",
          "availability": true,
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "make": "belt",
          "availability": false,
          "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

My task is to change the accessibility field. I have a button - change the availability. After clicking it I want to make the availability of a single field changed

```
 changeAvailability = (ailability, id) => {
    console.log(ailability)
    console.log(id)
    const { data } = this.state;
    let newData = [...data]
    this.setState({
      data: newData.map(x => x.id === id ? x.ailability = !ailability : ailability )
    })
  }
```

I have created a function that does not work.

My idea was: I click on the element, pass to the element's id and accessibility. In this function, I create a copy of the state. In the right place, I change the availability and I am sending everything to the state.

This function does not work, nothing happens, I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Be careful with `[...data]` as this only shallowly clones your data, so you're still mutating the original data. Not sure if thats why you are doing it though.

Comment: As far as I know, spread operation doesn't mutate the original data, neither does `Object.assign` per se. You can safely copy your state using `[...data]`

Comment: @Doe Did any of the answers satisfy your case?

Comment: @godof23  newData.map( auto => auto.id === id ? auto.availability = !auto.availability : auto.availability ) and 
    this.setState({
      data: newData
    })  . This was my code, which works

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the map function is returning nothing ...

Could be something like this

```
changeAvailability = (ailability, id) => {
    console.log(ailability)
    console.log(id)
    const { data } = this.state;
    let newData = [...data]
    const updateItem = (x) => {
       if (x.id === id) {
           x.ailability = !ailability;
       }
       return x;
    };

    this.setState({
      data: newData.map(updateItem)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to click on an element which passes an id and **availability** of an offer, find a matching entry (on the passed id) in the `offers` array in the state and change the **availability** of the found object to what you passed in the function.

I recommend using the callback that `this.setState()` allows you to use, providing a reference to a copy of the previous state, before the setState was called.

```
 changeAvailability = (passedAvail, passedID) => {
   this.setState((prevState) => {
     // Make a copy of the offers array in the state
     const offersArray = prevState.offers

     // Find index of matching obj by id
     const matchObjIndex = offersArray.findIndex(
       (offerObj) => (
         offerObj.id === passedID
       )
     )

     // If a match was indeed found
     if (matchObjIndex > -1) {
       // Find matching obj from index obtained
       const matchObj = offersArray[matchObjIndex]

       // Change the availibility of the matched obj and obtain a modified obj
       const modmatchObj = Object.assign(matchObj, {
         availability: passedAvail
       })

       // Replace the offer obj by index in the offers array.
       offersArray.splice(matchObjIndex, 1, modmatchObj);
     }

     // Finally set state with the updated offers lists
     // If no match was found, it will return the old offers array
     return {offers: offersArray }
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to make it work:

```js
 changeAvailability = (availability, id) =>
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                offers: prevState.offers.map((e, i) =>
                    e.id !== id ? e : { ...prevState.offers[i], availability }
                )
            };
        });
```

---

> The issue with your solution is that you shouldn't modify the items you're iterating while doing a map, but you should just return whatever new data you wanna add.